# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel' al enviar un mensaje a un canal espefico de discord con un bot hecho en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, hilos, discord.py

Este es el script main.py del bot:

```py
import discord, json, os
import random, time

from datetime import datetime

#Para poner mensajes por tiempo
import threading
import asyncio

main_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

""" Load Bot Configurations """
config_path = os.path.join(main_path, "config.json")
with open(config_path, "r") as jsonfile:
    bot_config = json.load(jsonfile)

from core.smartbot import SmartBot
from core.modules.bot_brain import BotBrain
from core.modules.bot_actions import BotActions

bot_modules = [BotBrain, BotActions]
ChatBot = SmartBot(bot_config, bot_modules, main_path)

class BotClient(discord.Client):
    @staticmethod
    def is_DMChannel(message: str) -> bool:
        """Verifica si es un mensaje proveniente es de un canal privado"""
        return isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel)

    def save_log(self, response: str, message: object) -> None:
        """Guarda el historial de conversacion"""
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        file_path = os.path.join(main_path, f"assets/log/{date.strftime('%d%b%y')}.txt")

        with open(file_path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
            text_file.write(f"{message.content}\n{response}\n")

    def load_content(self, name: str) -> dict:
        """Carga contenido .json de la carpeta embeds"""
        embed_path = os.path.join(main_path, f"assets/embeds/{name}.json")
        with open(embed_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as jsonfile:
            content = json.load(jsonfile)

        return content

    def create_embed(self, content: dict) -> object:
        """Crea un embed basado en el contenido de un diccionario"""
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=content["title"],
            description=content["description"],
            color=int(content["color"], 16),
        )

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=content["icon_url"])

        for key, value in content["content"].items():
            embed.add_field(name=key, value=value, inline=content["inline"])

        embed.set_footer(text=content["footer"])

        return embed

    def create_response(self, message: object) -> list:
        """Crea una respuesta en base al mensaje, y le da formato usando embeds"""

        response = ChatBot(message.content, str(message.author.id))
        if response != "#NoText":
            embed_content = self.load_content("msg_container")

            face_images = self.load_content("icon_urls")
            state = ChatBot.user_data[str(message.author.id)]["state"]
            if state in face_images:
                embed_content["icon_url"] = face_images[state]
            else:
                embed_content["icon_url"] = random.choice(list(face_images.values()))

            embed_content["description"] = f"`{response}`"
            embed = self.create_embed(embed_content)
        else:
            embed = None
        return response, embed

    async def send_response(self, message: object, is_server=False) -> None:
        """Envia una respuesta por el canal de proveniencia del mensaje."""
        response, embed = self.create_response(message)
        if bot_config["DebugMode"]:
            self.save_log(response, message)
            print(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")
            print(f"@ Bot: {response}")

        if response and response != "#notext" and embed:
            if is_server:
                await message.reply(embed=embed)
            else:
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    async def time_messege(self, message: object, is_server=False) -> None:

        alarmtime = "03:40"

        #greeting_channel = bot.get_channel(814238156396298310)

        while True:

            lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

            if lcltime == alarmtime:
                print("is time!")

                hello_strings = ("@everyone Holi!, como estan chic@s?", "@everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?", "everyone Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?", "@everyone Holi!, como se encuentran?") # Pongo las opciones de texto en una tupla y luego elijo una al azar con random.choice
                time_message = random.choice(hello_strings)
                #response, embed = message

                if bot_config["DebugMode"]:
                    print(f"@ Bot: {time_message}")

                #await message.get_channel(814238156396298310).send(embed=embed)
                #await get_channel(814238156396298310).send(embed=embed)
                await message.channel.send(time_message)

                await asyncio.sleep(90)

            else:
                print("not yet")
                await asyncio.sleep(10)


    def between_callback(self, args):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        loop.run_until_complete(self.time_messege(args))
        loop.close()


    #Ese metodo se ejecuta automaticamente cada vez que el bot se enciende
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:

        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        #x = threading.Thread(target=time_messege) #Creo un thread independiente del main_thread
        #x.start()

        _thread = threading.Thread(target=self.between_callback, args=("some text", ))
        _thread.start()


    async def on_message(self, message: object) -> None:
        if not message.author.bot:
            if message.content.startswith(bot_config["prefix"]):
                args = message.content.split(" ", 1)
                command = args[0][len(bot_config["prefix"]):]

                if command.lower() == "fit":
                    ChatBot.fit(args[1], str(message.author.id))

            else:
                if self.is_DMChannel(message):
                    await self.send_response(message)

                elif not self.is_DMChannel(message) and self.user in message.mentions:
                    await self.send_response(message, is_server=True)


def ConsoleChat():
    """Permite utilizar al bot en la consola"""
    fake_user = "Anonimous"
    while True:
        text = input("User >> ")
        if text.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            response = ChatBot(text, fake_user)
            if response != "#NoText":
                print(f"Bot: {response}")
            else:
                print("*Parece que el bot no quiere responder*")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BotClient().run(bot_config["BotToken"]) #Online para Discord
    #ConsoleChat()  #Offline desde Consola
```

Este es el bot si bien este anda pero el error esta en el thread que conecta con la funcion async def time_messege(self, message: object, is_server=False) , osea aquella que se deberia encargar de enviar mensajes directos sin que este a la espera de que alguien le escriba para poder responderle por el mismo medio (por privado o por el canal del server asociado (el bot cuenta con permisos de administrador) )

Este es el error/es que me sale/en , estube ya probando de varias maneras y no consigo enviar un mensaje especifico a un canal especifico directamente con este script, que modificaciones sugieren?

para mi el problema esta con esto:

Si uso esta instruccion:

```
await message.channel.send(time_message)
```

da este error:

```py
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
is time!
@ Bot: @everyone Holi!, como se encuentran?
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 133, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(self.time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main_greetings.py", line 120, in time_messege
    await message.channel.send(time_message)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 163, in on_message
    await self.send_response(message, is_server=True)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 87, in send_response
    self.save_log(response, message)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 32, in save_log
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 163, in on_message
    await self.send_response(message, is_server=True)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 87, in send_response
    self.save_log(response, message)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 32, in save_log
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Si uso esta otra instruccion:

```
await get_channel(814238156396298310).send(embed=embed)
```

sale este error:

```py
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
not yet
is time!
@ Bot: @everyone Holi!, como estan chic@s?
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 134, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(self.time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main_greetings.py", line 121, in time_messege
    await message.channel.send(embed=time_message)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

Comment: Por alguna razón `get_channel()` te devuelve un string en vez de un objeto channel, haz un print de `get_channel()` y mera lo que trae

Comment: da str seguro, el tema es que no se como hacer ese get_channel por que me dice que NameError: name 'get_channel' is not defined

Comment: No deberías hacerlo de esta forma `Clienr.get_channel()`? Con la instancia del cliente

Comment: coloque el Client.get_channel(), osea quedando asi esa linea:  await Client.get_channel(814238156396298310).send(embed=embed), peor me sale el error de que NameError: name 'Client' is not defined ?

La verdad que pense que estaria asociado pero no...

Comment: debes de colocar la instacia de tu bot, esta es la forma en lo inicializas

Comment: @Christian en este caso creo que seria BotClient() , no?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124263/discussion-between-christian-and-electrisik-vocal).

Comment: Esta bien ahi lo inicie por chat mejor